# How to Change order of background-image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with 2 images for `background-image` with CSS code:

```
background: url(img/over.png),url(img/bg.png);
```

With this code it first shows `bg.png` and then `over.png`

Now I want to know how I can change the order of showing the images in JavaScript dynamically?

Comment: @Jashaszun he's tagged only javascript. i think he's not looking for a jquery option

Comment: @Sushil Ah I didn't realize that's how it works in this tag. Sorry.

Comment: no problem @Jashaszun :)

Comment: its better for me that suggest a pure javascript solution

Comment: yeah i see that the jquery tag has been added. @Jashaszun you can post your solution

Answer (score 0):

I used this in one of my app, if you have the array of the background images that would be great

The trick behind to show image one is `background-size:100% 100%, 0% 100%;` and the second image is `background-size:0% 100%, 100% 100%;`

```
function sliderAnimation(ind){
    //console.log(ind);
    var slider = $('#slideout'); //#slideout is having your background images
    var l = slider.css('background-image').split(',');
    if(slider.length){
        var size = [], position = [];
        var allItemsLen = l.length;
        for(var i=0; i<allItemsLen;i++){
            if(i<ind){
                size.push('0% 100%');
                position.push('left center');
            }else if(i==ind){
                size.push('100% 100%');
                position.push('right center');
            }else if(i>ind){
                size.push('0% 100%');
                position.push('right center');
            }
        }
        if(ind==allItemsLen-1){
            size[0] = ('0% 100%');
            position[0] = ('right center');
            ind = 0;
        }else if(ind==0){
            size[allItemsLen-1] = ('0% 100%');
            position[allItemsLen-1] = ('left center');
            ind++;
        }else ind++;
        slider.css({'background-size': size.join(','),'background-position': position.join(',')});
        //when = true;
    }
    homeSLideInt = setTimeout(function(){sliderAnimation(ind)},5000);
}
```

call this once with `sliderAnimation(0)` once and it will loop every 5 seconds.

Comment: its good solution but i want change order of existing backgroundimge...it like z-index in show backgroungimage only

Comment: @combo_ci Its for existing images on background size check out <div id=slideout should have all your backgrounds separated by `,` all good

Comment: it rotates all images as like one on top of the other

Comment: The trick behind to show image one is `background-size:100% 100%, 0% 100%;` and the second image is `background-size:0% 100%, 100% 100%;`